# Python | Working with JSON

Tags: python, json

I need to extract data out of json to a csv file.
working with csv / excel in python is a breeze but I never handled json data.

I know that there is a json lib for python but the documentation isn't so helpful.

This is an example of a json file :

```
{"properties": 
    {
        "$initial_referring_domain": "$direct", 
        "$screen_height": 1080, 
        "$city": "Melbourne", 
        "$initial_referrer": "$direct", 
        "$screen_width": 1920, 
        "mp_country_code": "AU", 
        "$region": "Victoria", 
    }, 
    "distinct_id": "151", 
    "sampling_factor": 133, 
    "name": "login", 
    "time": 53000
}
```

I need to separate my files,
one to include only the properties and the other for all the rest.

I'm not looking for a whole solution (not that I mind) but rather to get some guidance to understand how to solve it by myself.

Thanks !

Comment: After you load file by `o = json.load(file_obj)` everything from JSON file is (nested) python object. You may access dictionary fields with `d['key']` syntax, index lists with `l[index]` syntax. What's unclear here?

Comment: @Rogalski , I tried to loop the keys but I get an error that my dict. isn't iterable.